# Chronometer counting in characters

Tags: android

I just added a chronometer to my app and it has a weird behavior. Instead of counting in numbers it's doing it in CHARS!
Example:

```
00:00:00
00:00:0(
00:00:0)
00:00:0/
00:00:0*
00:00:0+
... LOOPS AFTER 10
00:00:00
00:00:0(
00:00:0)
00:00:0/
00:00:0*
00:00:0+
```

xml

```
        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/tracking_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/record_indicator"
            android:textColor="@color/tracking_time"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

onCreate

```
        mTrackingTime = (Chronometer)this.findViewById(R.id.tracking_time);
        mTrackingTime.setOnChronometerTickListener(this);
```

start

```
    mTrackingTime.setBase(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mTrackingTime.start();
```

callback

```
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(final Chronometer chronometer) {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding `Chronometer.setBase()` wants millisecond based on the [elapsedRealTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29). This means that epoch milliseconds don't work. In order to be able to use epoch milliseconds, you have to call `Chronometer.setBase()` like following:

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
```

The math effectively converts the epoch milliseconds to elapsed real time milliseconds.

Try this and see if that fixes your problem...

Updated as per @Ef Es comment..

Comment: It gives me a huge inaccurate number :/ Also, I don't think it does what I want from him, just a simple chronometer.

Answer (score 2):

These characters appear when the base is larger than `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`, which is the milliseconds since boot.

It displays the result of this argument:

```
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - base
```

The default, or if you call:

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
```

Then the chronometer will start from `00:00`

If you call:

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - 10000);
```

Then the chronometer will start from `00:10`

If you call:

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10000);
```

Then the chronometer will draw rubbish for 10 seconds, and than start from `00:00`

So if you call:

```
chronometer.setBase(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

You should expect to see rubbish for about 44 years, and than it will be ok.